# how to make tess4j work with Deutsche language

Tags: java, tesseract

I am currently using Tess4J in order to integrate tesseract within my java program.

Is it possible for me to work with  lang.traineddata files like deu.traineddata , and afterwards just include this in my tessdata folder used by my Tess4J wrapper from my java program.

because i tried to include the deu.traineddata in tessdata folder used it on a Deutsche document but the result is the same as using only English eng.traineddata

i don't know if i have to include something in the config , how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`setLanguage`](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-1.2/) method.

Comment: where can i make this call ? because in my project i only have 2 dlls and some jars , the jars containing some compiled files ( .class) , so where can i make the modifications

Comment: set Language method is called like calling doOCR method ? or i have to change in the configuration?

Comment: thank you for your answer i found the method setLanguage

Comment: What happen if I don't set the language and I scan a picture (let's say a business card) in Arabian? Does it guess or find the language?

Comment: @franzmobile It defaults to English. You have to specify the language yourself.